Get-ACL of Deleted Objects Container
I am trying to update the ACL permissions of the 'Deleted Objects' container in AD programmatically however I am unable to validate the current permissions. Normally I would use Get-ACL on the Distinguished Name however this command returns "Cannot find path {DN} because it does not exist"
I am running this as a Domain Admin and I can confirm the container does exist with Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADDomain).DeletedObjectsContainer) -Filter * -IncludeDeletedObjects -SearchScope Base The issue seems to be that the Deleted Objects container itself is marked as isDeleted which prevents Get-ACL from reading it.
Using dsacls as outlined here does work if I run it as system through psexec though the output is not ideal as I have to process it before I can validate against it. Is there another way to query this information with PowerShell that will return cleaner output?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/non-administrators-view-deleted-object-container

Are you an admin or owner of the object?

I am running this as an account in the Domain Admins group but even running as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM which is the Owner and Group of the container Get-ACL thinks the container does not exist, this seems like an issue/oversight with the powershell command itself rather than a permissions issue.

Not all Admin are the same.  There are multiple Admins and just because you are an Admin doesn't mean you have access to the file.  I think you are access the file on the local machine, but the file could be linked to a file on another machine.  Powershell is written in Net so if the issue exists in PS than it also exists in Net.  Is fie on a Window Machine or Linux/Mac?

My account is a member of 'Domain Admins' which is a member of 'BUILTIN\Administrators' which has explicit read permission to the container in question.
I can't say whether the issue is with the PowerShell command or the underlying .Net functions but it shouldn't be a permissions issue as even running the Get-ACL command as 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' which the ACL rules indicate is the owner and has full access to the container I am getting the does not exist error.
I am just going to use dsacls with some ugly regex to validate permissions and open a ticket with MS to fix the command.

You are probably correct.  Are all machines in the same Domain?  Are all machines using the same type credentials?  Many systems are moving from Window credentials to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 works with Windows, Linux, and MAC.  I worked for a very large company with multiple divisions, multiple locations and multiple domains.  There were a lot of protection. Admins in one division did not have access to data in another division.  There were on a few Admin and corporate level that had access to all locations.

You're right, you do have to treat it specially because it's "deleted".
You were very close. You can return the nTSecurityDescriptor property of the AD Object which will get you what you want.
$delObjContainer = Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "container"' -SearchBase (Get-ADDomain).DeletedObjectsContainer -Properties nTSecurityDescriptor -IncludeDeletedObjects -SearchScope base
$delObjContainer.nTSecurityDescriptor.Access

# ActiveDirectoryRights : CreateChild, DeleteChild, ListChildren, ReadProperty, Delete, GenericWrite, WriteDacl, WriteOwner
# InheritanceType       : None
# ObjectType            : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
# InheritedObjectType   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
# ObjectFlags           : None
# AccessControlType     : Allow
# IdentityReference     : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
# IsInherited           : False
# InheritanceFlags      : None
# PropagationFlags      : None


This is what I was looking for, thanks!
